# generating method headers in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any way by which i can generate method headers in eclipse?

Eg:If i already have a method in my code:

```
public void doSomething(String name,String age){
}
```

Expected OP

```
 /*
    *This method does something
    *@param name  name of employee
    *@param age  age of employee
    */
    public void doSomething(String name,String age){

    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Type

```
/**
Enter
```

Afterwards Eclipse will generate you a default java-doc.

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to do this:

- Use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> when your cursor is anywhere within your method or on the method header
- Use `Rightclick -> Source -> Generate Element Comment` to generate Javadoc comments in your editor window

The templates for these comments can be customized in the template section of the preferences:
`Window -> Preferences` and then `Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates`

Answer (score 2):

`RIGHT CLICK` --> `Source` --> `Generate Element Comment`

or just click on <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>